# Looking for a mail from a colleague in my MS Inbox - but it came from no-reply@sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am looking for a mail from a colleague in my MS Outlook Inbox - but it came from no-reply@sharepoint.... When I search on my colleague's name the mail is not found.  When I search on 'no-reply@sharepoint' [the sender] - the mail is also not found.  Hence my question is - how do I search for this type of mail ?  Which search string do I use ?
Thanks, Simon

Comment: Try your colleagues name + `<no-reply@sharepoint.com>`, something like `John Smith <no-reply@sharepoint.com>`

Comment: Thanks for posting ! Unfortunately the mail I am looking for doesn't appear in the search results.

Comment: This should work (it works at least in my Outlook client) what client are you using?

Comment: I am using Outlook, part of Microsoft 365 ProPlus - i'll try again later this afternoon.